# Either you can't really pass part of an array like this.. or something is very weird

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

The aim of the program I'm writing is to implement a genetic algorithm to develop playing strategies for the stochastic game Piglet. To begin with, I have an array holding all the strategies, and I pass the array with one index specified to the 'fitness' function. Just to check everything was working fine, I had it print the strategy (only had 1 in the population at this point for the sake of simplicity of these tests). And well.. it kinda worked; I had a 10x10x10 array of zeroes and ones which it's supposed to do, but the program carried on printing numbers; sometimes blocks of zeroes, sometimes blocks of ridiculously large numbers. I think my call of fitness might be the issue.. I've never seen/been told this is possible, but I didn't see why it wouldn't be, so gave it a go.

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

#define STRATS 1

double fitness(int strategy[10][10][10]){

    for (int i=0; i<10; ++i) {
        printf("\n\n");
        for (int j=0; j<10; ++j) {
            printf("\n");
            for (int k=0; k<10; ++k) {
                printf("%d ", strategy[i][j][k]);
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

int main () {

    int strategies[STRATS][10][10][10]; /*[strategy reference][i][j][k]*/
    int fitnesses[STRATS];

    /*Generate initial strategies*/

    for (int s=0; s<STRATS; ++s) {
        for (int i=0; i<10; ++i) {
            for (int j=0; j<10; ++j) {
                for (int k=0; k<10; ++k) {
                    strategies[s][i][j][k]=random()%2;  /*Populate the i,j,k's with ones and zereos randomly*/
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /*Begin evolutionary procedure*/

    /*Compute fitness of each strategy*/

    for (int s=0; s<20; ++s) {
        fitnesses[s]=fitness(strategies[s]);
    }

    /*Choose 2 for breeding*/

    /*Breed the strategies*/

    /*Perform a mutation on the child*/

    /*Choose strategy to be replaced and put child in its place*/

    while (1==1) {}

    return 0;
}
```

Here's a snippet of some of the very random output I get after it's completed what I actually need:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 -17958193 16777223 3 7 9 1856 133 0 
25 792 1163157343 21592 0 0 1606418432 32767 245760 0 
0 0 245760 0 7 5 9 0 1702125407 29816 
0 0 1163157343 21592 0 0 1606422528 32767 146750 0 
4096 4 0 0 -2147482624 0 0 0 1951620959 1667855457 


1953066569 0 1163157343 21592 0 0 1606569278 32767 1025 0 
150846 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1935892319 1852404340 
103 0 1163157343 21592 0 0 1606570304 32767 35849 0 
151872 3 0 0 2 0 0 0 1868783455 7631726 
0 0 1163157343 21592 0 0 1606606176 32767 192 0 
187744 5 0 0 0 0 0 0 1868848991 1819303782 
1936417647 7627124 1163157343 21592 0 0 1606606368 32767 2988 0 
187936 4 0 0 15 0 0 0 1868848991 2019778406 
1970429793 6911086 1163157343 21592 0 0 1606609360 32767 1956 0 
190928 4 0 0 15 0 0 0 1667719007 2019909475
```

Comment: oh god a 4d array... why?

Comment: Well, the objects I need are intrinsically 3 dimensional, since they have 3 independent parameters! The fourth I don't strictly need.. but it would be far easier for controlling the size of the population throughout the program with it!

Comment: try this: `printf("%d ", strategy[0][i][j][k]);`

Comment: Well you create strategies as a `[1][10][10][10]` then try to access `strategies[0]` through `strategies[19]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Failure because code accesses outside its memory.

```
#define STRATS 1
...
int strategies[STRATS][10][10][10];
...
// for (int s=0; s<20; ++s) {
for (int s=0; s<STRATS; ++s) {
```

Maybe change to `#define STRATS (20)`

Comment: This highlighted that I forgot to change that 20 to STRATS. That fixed it! Thanks. (I'll answer this once I can)

Answer (score 1):

This loop

```
for (int s=0; s<20; ++s) {
    fitnesses[s]=fitness(strategies[s]);
}
```

assumes there are 20 subordinate arrays of 20x20x20, but you really allocated only one by defining `STRATS` to have the value 1.

If you change the loop limit above from `20` to `STRATS`, then all will be consistent.